# What CMD command will append a file to piped input

Tags: windows, cmd

What CMD command will append a file to piped input?

I.e. what command xxx will cause the line

```
type a.txt | xxx b.txt
```

to output the content of a.txt followed by b.txt?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a pipe. simly run `type a.txt b.txt`

If you do not want the file names you can concat both calls of type with and & : `type a.txt & type b.txt`

Comment: If you specify multiple files, `type` will "helpfully" include the file names in the output. This is, of course, almost never what you want.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for pointing that out. Look at my edited answer

Comment: @JeroenMostert: thanksfully, `type` outputs the "helpful" filenames on STDERR. So `type *.* 2>nul` suppresses them.

Comment: `type a.txt b.txt 2>nul`

Comment: @JeroenMostert: you don't have to understand it. It's sufficient to outsmart it... `:D`

Comment: If you're writing to a pipe, put the concatenated `type` commands in parentheses:  `(type a.txt & type b.txt) | anothercommand`.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method. Still though I'd be interested in an answer to the question as given.